# Mysql tekes too much time to excute sql query, based on multiple join

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

My Sql query takes more time to execute from mysql database server . There are number of tables are joined with sb_tblproperty table. sb_tblproperty is main table that contain more than 1,00,000 rows . most of table contain 50,000 rows.

How to optimize my sql query to fast execution. I have also used indexing.

[indexing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQHGU.jpg) [Explain - query - structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dez5t.jpg)

```
SELECT `t1`.`propertyId`, `t1`.`projectId`,
`t1`.`furnised`, `t1`.`ownerID`, `t1`.`subType`,
`t1`.`fors`, `t1`.`size`, `t1`.`unit`,
`t1`.`bedrooms`, `t1`.`address`, `t1`.`dateConfirm`,
`t1`.`dateAdded`, `t1`.`floor`, `t1`.`priceAmount`,
`t1`.`priceRate`, `t1`.`allInclusive`, `t1`.`booking`,
`t1`.`bookingRate`, `t1`.`paidPercetage`,
`t1`.`paidAmount`, `t1`.`is_sold`, `t1`.`remarks`,
`t1`.`status`, `t1`.`confirmedStatus`, `t1`.`source`,
`t1`.`companyName` as company, `t1`.`monthly_rent`,
`t1`.`per_sqft`, `t1`.`lease_duration`,
`t1`.`lease_commencement`, `t1`.`lock_in_period`,
`t1`.`security_deposit`, `t1`.`security_amount`,
`t1`.`total_area_leased`, `t1`.`lease_escalation_amount`,
`t1`.`lease_escalation_years`, `t2`.`propertyTypeName` as
propertyTypeName, `t3`.`propertySubTypeName` subType,
`t3`.`propertySubTypeId` subTypeId, `Owner`.`ContactName`
ownerName, `Owner`.`companyName`, `Owner`.`mobile1`,
`Owner`.`otherPhoneNo`, `Owner`.`mobile2`,
`Owner`.`email`, `Owner`.`address` as caddress,
`Owner`.`contactType`, `P`.`projectName` as project,
`P`.`developerName` as developer, `c`.`name` as city,
if(t1.projectId="", group_concat( distinct( L.locality)),
group_concat( distinct(L2.locality))) as locality, `U`.`firstname`
addedBy, `U1`.`firstname` confirmedBy 
FROM `sb_tblproperty` as t1   
JOIN `sb_contact` Owner ON `Owner`.`id` = `t1`.`ownerID` 
JOIN `tbl_city` C ON `c`.`id` = `t1`.`city` 
JOIN `sb_propertytype` t2 ON `t1`.`propertyType`= `t2`.`propertyTypeId` 
JOIN `sb_propertysubtype` t3 ON `t1`.`subType` =`t3`.`propertySubTypeId` 
LEFT JOIN `sb_tbluser` U ON `t1`.`addedBy` = `U`.`userId` 
LEFT JOIN`sb_tbluser` U1 ON `t1`.`confirmedBy` = `U1`.`userId` 
LEFT JOIN `sb_tblproject` P ON `P`.`id` = `t1`.`projectId` LEFT
JOIN `sb_tblpropertylocality` PL ON `t1`.`propertyId` = `PL`.`propertyId` 
LEFT JOIN `sa_localitiez` L ON `L`.`id` = `PL`.`localityId` 
LEFT JOIN `sb_tblprojectlocality` PROL ON `PROL`.`projectId` = `P`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `sa_localitiez` L2 ON `L2`.`id` = `PROL`.`localityId`
LEFT JOIN `sb_tblfloor` F
ON `F`.`floorName` =`t1`.`floor`
WHERE `t1`.`is_sold` != '1' GROUP BY `t1`.`propertyId` 
ORDER BY `t1`.`dateConfirm`
DESC LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: you should add the table structure, list of indexes and a query execution plan (with EXPLAIN <your query>), if you want people to help...

Comment: try [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) on your query to see if it uses your indexes. if not you have to create betetr indexes

Comment: Do you have an index on `sb_tblfloor.floorName` ?

Comment: @Olli , Yes I have use Index sb_tblfloor.floorName

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the `EXPLAIN`.

Meanwhile, try this:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM (
        SELECT propertyId
            FROM sb_tblproperty
            WHERE `is_sold` = 0
            ORDER BY `dateConfirm` DESC
            LIMIT 1000
         ) AS x
    JOIN `sb_tblproperty` as t1   ON t1.propertyId = x.propertyId
    JOIN `sb_contact` Owner  ON `Owner`.`id` = `t1`.`ownerID` 
    JOIN `tbl_city` C  ON `c`.`id` = `t1`.`city`
    ... 
    LEFT JOIN `sb_tblfloor` F  ON `F`.`floorName` =`t1`.`floor`
    ORDER BY `t1`.`dateConfirm` DESC   -- yes, again
```

Together with

```
INDEX(is_sold, dateConfirm)
```

How can t1.projectId="" ?  Isn't projectId the PRIMARY KEY?  (This is one of many reasons for needing the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

If my suggestion leads to "duplicate" rows (that is, multiple rows with the same `propertyId`), don't simply add back the `GROUP BY propertyId`.  Instead figure out why, and avoid the need for the `GROUP BY`.  (That is probably the performance issue.)

A likely case is the `GROUP_CONCAT`.  A common workaround is to change from

```
GROUP_CONCAT( distinct( L.locality)) AS Localities,
...
LEFT JOIN `sa_localitiez` L ON `L`.`id` = `PL`.`localityId`
```

to

```
( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(distinct locality)
         FROM sa_localitiez
         WHERE id = PL.localityId ) AS Localities
...
# and remove the JOIN
```

Comment: Hi, @Rick Jame Here the Link of Explain Structure 
[link] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/dez5t.jpg)

Comment: You are not using F at all?  Get rid of "LEFT JOIN `sb_tblfloor` F
ON `F`.`floorName` =`t1`.`floor`" it seems to be doing nothing but wasting time.